# SonarQube 4.5.7 to 5.6.5 DB Upgrade failure

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I have attempted to upgrade our SonarQube instance from 4.5.7 LTS to 5.6.5 LTS. I followed the provided SonarQube upgrade documentation. After browsing to [sonarserver]:9000/setup and ran the DB Upgrade. The upgrade ran a little over 2 hours and came back with this message:

```
Upgrade Failed

Database connection cannot be established. Please check database status and JDBC settings.
```

When viewing the log, I see this error:

```
2017.02.16 13:18:43 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.DatabaseMigrator] Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.db.version.v50.FeedFileSources
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error during processing of row: [uuid=AVpHrbhU29-XDi5QdhtN,uuid=AVpHrbk629-XDi5Qdh0r,data=using System;
```

I have copied the entire db upgrade log here: http://pastebin.com/p9CkYhrU

I also tried to restart SonarQube and attempt the db upgrade again, but it ran for 5-10 mins and reported the same result.

Additional Details:

Current SonarQube: 4.5.7 LTS

New SonarQube: 5.6.5 LTS

DB: MySQL 5.7.17

Operating System: Windows Server 2012 R2

After the unsuccessful upgrade, we reverted back to 4.5.7 successfully.

We also previously upgraded from 4.3.1 to 4.5.7 LTS. During this upgrade, we moved our SonarQube database from MySQL 5.5 to 5.7.17 and then upgraded SonarQube to 4.5.7 LTS. The upgrade step for this ran two hours and completed successfully.

Thank you for any assistance,

-Eddie

Comment: It looks like you hit another variant of an upgrade bug related to FeedFileSources. See [here](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7997) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/hOkvq3jz6kI). You could investigate the tables mentioned in the links trying to find something unusual data and repair it. Because this is an upgrade between LTS versions you should also search in the SonarQube Google groups for an answer or post a detailed question. As a last resort you have to start again with a empty database.

Comment: The [code](https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code-detail.php?file=./javaSource/org.sonarsource.sonarqube/sonar-db/5.6/org/sonar/db/version/v50/FeedFileSources.java&key=c958548c567e504e88ff12dee402c385) is also available

Comment: @JeroenHeier Thanks! I was able to work through the error and found some more! I posted what I did as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2/21/17**

I stood up a test instance for this SonarQube upgrade on a different server. I installed MySQL 5.7 and SonarQube 4.5.7 LTS using the same backup data. During the upgrade to SonarQube 5.6.5 LTS, I received the same error as before. So I knew at this point that I could duplicate the error. I decided to look at that error message again and found these a bit further down:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Packet for query is too large         (6371233 > 4194304). You can change this value on the server by setting the         max_allowed_packet' variable.

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too     large (6371233 > 4194304). You can change this value on the server by setting     the `max_allowed_packet` variable.
```

So I went ahead and edited the `max_allowed_packet` variable in my.ini. First I changed it from 4M to 8M and received a similar error. Next, I changed the variable to 16M and the upgrade got past the error!

Unfortunately, the DB Upgrade ran for 11 more hours and came back with another error:

```
2017.02.21 02:48:13 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.DatabaseMigrator] Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.db.version.v564.CleanUsurperRootComponents
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error during processing of row: [id=62566,uuid=AVpc2I0gt4GsKrhSYYYQ]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Application was streaming results when the connection failed. Consider raising value of 'net_write_timeout' on the server.
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

I increased the net_read_timeout in mysql from 60 to 1200. `set net_write_timeout = 1200;` I restarted SonarQube, ran the DB Upgrade again, and got past the error. The upgrade continued running and I received another error:

```
2017.02.21 09:57:05 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB Migration or container restart failed. Process ended with an exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to load plugin Clirr [clirr]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/api/batch/maven/DependsUponMavenPlugin
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.api.batch.maven.DependsUponMavenPlugin
```

Looks like a plugin error, so I went ahead and looked into that individual   plugin. I found some information about the Clirr plugin being deprecated, so I removed it from the Plugins folder, restarted SonarQube, and got hit with another plugin error (different plugin). I got 6 or 7 of these errors and was able to fix them by either removing or replacing the .jar in the Plugins folder with the newer compatible version.

So after fixing the Java plugin, I restarted SonarQube and it started up fine! I am now running SonarQube 5.6.5 LTS on my sandbox server. The next step will be for me to revert back to 4.5.7 LTS and try the upgrade again to be sure I will have a successful production upgrade in the future.

Comment: A very good report! It is indeed a good idea before starting the upgrade to review all plugins. Remove the deprecated and also update all others, Create also a new folder, copy the new SonarQube version into it and copy the plugin jars from the old folder. Also reindex your database after upgrade.